# User to return to main menu if yes is selected

Tags: java, netbeans

Hi guys i am having an issue with how to do this, i have googled it but its not making much sense. 
i need to do this;
The program asks the user if they wish to continue.
 If Yes is selected, it will return to the Main menu.
 If No is selected, Total Amount Payable will be
displayed and then the program will terminate

```
  int option, quantity, confirm;
  float childTotal;
  float adultTotal;
  float seniorTotal;

  final double childCost = 18;
  final double adultCost = 36;
  final double seniorCost = 32.50;

  char resume;

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("1 = Child (4-6 yrs)");
    System.out.println("2 = Adult (16+ yrs)");
    System.out.println("3 = Senior (60+ yrs)" + "\n");

    System.out.println("Enter your option:" );
    option=input.nextInt();

    switch (option) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Enter total No of tickets for Child:" );
            quantity=input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("You are purchasing " + quantity + " child tickets");

            System.out.println("Press 1 to confirm");
            confirm=input.nextInt();

            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("Enter total No of tickets for Adult:" );
            quantity=input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("You are purchasing " + quantity + " adult tickets");

            System.out.println("Press 1 to confirm");
            confirm=input.nextInt();

            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Enter total No of tickets for Senior:" );
            quantity=input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("You are purchasing " + quantity + " senior tickets");

            System.out.println("Press 1 to confirm");
            confirm=input.nextInt();

            break;
    }

    if (confirm !=1) {
        System.out.println("Incorrect key! User to go back to main menu");
    }


  System.out.println("Do you wish to continue? (Y/N) ");
  resume = input.next().charAt(0);

  if (resume == 'y' || resume == 'Y') {

} else {
      switch (option) {
            case 1:
                childTotal=(int) ((double) quantity*childCost) ;
                System.out.println("Total amount for child tickets: $" + childTotal);
                break;
            case 2:
                adultTotal=(int) ((double) quantity*adultCost) ;
                System.out.println("Total amount for adult tickets $" + adultTotal);
                break;
            default:
                seniorTotal=(int) ((double) quantity*seniorCost);
                System.out.println("Total amount for senior tickets $" + seniorTotal);
                break;
        }
  }
```

Comment: add the whole code into a loop and loop it until the user selects no.

Comment: Add continue; after System.out.println("Incorrect key! User to go back to main menu");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Boolean variable set as true.

```
boolean continueLoop = true;
```

Add your main logic into a while loop until continue is true

```
while(continueLoop){
  //Do your code here
  System.out.println("Do you wish to continue? (Y/N) ");
  resume = input.next().charAt(0);
  if (resume == 'y' || resume == 'Y'){}
  else{
  //Do Code here
   continueLoop=false;
   }
} //End while loop.
```

After the while loop continue with your code. I have changed the condition of resume == y to resume !=y because if the user does not press y the code should stop iterating.

Your code would become

```
int option, quantity, confirm;
        float childTotal;
        float adultTotal;
        float seniorTotal;

        final double childCost = 18;
        final double adultCost = 36;
        final double seniorCost = 32.50;

        boolean continueLoop = true;
        char resume;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(continueLoop){
                System.out.println("1 = Child (4-6 yrs)");
                System.out.println("2 = Adult (16+ yrs)");
                System.out.println("3 = Senior (60+ yrs)" + "\n");

                System.out.println("Enter your option:" );
                option=input.nextInt();

                switch (option) {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("Enter total No of tickets for Child:" );
                        quantity=input.nextInt();

                        System.out.println("You are purchasing " + quantity + " child tickets");

                        System.out.println("Press 1 to confirm");
                        confirm=input.nextInt();

                        break;

                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("Enter total No of tickets for Adult:" );
                        quantity=input.nextInt();

                        System.out.println("You are purchasing " + quantity + " adult tickets");

                        System.out.println("Press 1 to confirm");
                        confirm=input.nextInt();

                        break;

                    default:
                        System.out.println("Enter total No of tickets for Senior:" );
                        quantity=input.nextInt();

                        System.out.println("You are purchasing " + quantity + " senior tickets");

                        System.out.println("Press 1 to confirm");
                        confirm=input.nextInt();

                        break;
                }

                if (confirm !=1) {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect key! User to go back to main menu");
                }


              System.out.println("Do you wish to continue? (Y/N) ");
              resume = input.next().charAt(0);

              if (resume == 'y' || resume == 'Y') {
              }else{
                  continueLoop = false;
                  switch (option) {
                    case 1:
                        childTotal=(int) ((double) quantity*childCost) ;
                        System.out.println("Total amount for child tickets: $" + childTotal);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        adultTotal=(int) ((double) quantity*adultCost) ;
                        System.out.println("Total amount for adult tickets $" + adultTotal);
                        break;
                    default:
                        seniorTotal=(int) ((double) quantity*seniorCost);
                        System.out.println("Total amount for senior tickets $" + seniorTotal);
                        break;
                  }
              }
        }
    }
```

Comment: also remove the else from below and continue the code after the while loop.

Comment: continue is a keyword in java and may not be used

Comment: hi where do i add this?

Comment: @Bec add the Boolean introduction to the top, while loop should start after scanner input

Comment: @FarhanQasim I have done this but it doesn't continue after I enter 'y', just states build successful

Comment: @Bec edit your question and post your whole code attempt. Ill see whats the issue